# Trying to select multiple ranges using defined variables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to change the current line of code to be variable - instead of using row 50, use "prog_end3a"

```
Range(prog_shift_1 & "50:" & subj_ec & "50," & prog_shift_1 & prog_end3a + i & ":" & subj_ec & 50 + i).Copy
```

I can't figure out how to properly replace 50 with prog_end3a so that it still selects the two ranges separately. Can anyone help? Also, I know I have option explicit turned off, but its necessary for this circumstance.

Comment: What's `prog_end3a` declared as, and how did you define it?

Comment: `prog_shift_1 & prog_end3a & ":" & subj_ec & prog_end3a & "," ...` *this assumes `prog_end3a` variables hold the value of `50` (or whatever row number). If your variables are defined as ranges, than completely different answer. ....  **I know I have option explicit turned off, but its necessary for this circumstance** ... I can't imagine a good reason to ever turn it off.

Comment: The fact that you already know how to use `prog_end3a` in your range definition (i.e. you are already using `... prog_shift_1 & prog_end3a + i & ":" ...`), and your mention of `Option Explicit` not being used, makes me think that your issue is not with the line of code you posted but elsewhere in your code.  Perhaps you should post enough of your code so that we can see what your issue is.